# How to download a page contents when the header is 404 using VB,NET WebClient

Tags: vb.net, download, webclient

An interesting issue arose where I would like to download the page contents even if the page returns a 404 in the header response.

The code I have currently, is as follows :

```
Public Function CheckLink(ByVal YouTubeID As String) As Boolean
    Dim url As String = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" & YouTubeID
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Try
        Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(url)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

The problem I am having is I would like the value stored in `result`, however if a 404 occurs, it raises a general exception.  When using PHP, I can download the contents of a page and not have to trap any errors because the headers.  I find this is rather strange as it prevents the download of contents when the header gives a 404, or essentially anything other than 200 OK.  Is there any way I can override this default behavior so that no matter what the header is that is returned from the server, that I can still access the contents -- and without having to try/catch block this idiocy ??

I understand try/catch in the event the server can not be contacted, or for socket/communication errors, however in this event, the server is responding, but it still causes an exception even though content is returned.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I were you, I'd declare Result prior to the try/catch, run that line without the declaration, have it catch the exception, and see if after the try if result still has the grabbed value. It might not because webclient has a lot of protections in it, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I tried that in other attempts.  Sadly, the dumb "errors" in WebClient stop at the header.